# Error while installing minishift: Checking if Hyper-V driver is installed ... FAIL

Tags: minishift

I've been following the steps to install minishift on my local machine. All the commands seem to work correctly until I get to the point where I need to create a virtual switch and set HyperV as the default driver. I followed the steps to create a virtual switch called "External VM Switch". When I try to start minishift, I'm always getting a **FAIL** when it checks if the 'Hyper-V driver is installed'. I've followed the steps on the suggested documentation but even after completing them I am still getting the same error when I try to start minishift.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minishift config set vm-driver hyperv
No Minishift instance exists. New 'vm-driver' setting will be applied on next 'minishift start'

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> minishift start --hyperv-virtual-switch "External VM Switch"
-- Starting profile 'minishift'
-- Check if deprecated options are used ...
   Use of HYPERV_VIRTUAL_SWITCH has been deprecated
   Please use: minishift config set hyper-virtual-switch External
FAIL

-- Checking if https://github.com is reachable ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.9.0' is valid ... OK
-- Checking if requested OpenShift version 'v3.9.0' is supported ... OK
-- Checking if requested hypervisor 'hyperv' is supported on this platform ... OK
-- Checking if Hyper-V driver is installed ... FAIL
   See the 'Setting Up the Virtualization Environment' topic (https://docs.openshift.org/latest/minishift/getting-started/setting-up-virtualization-environment.html) for more information
```

[image: Added External VM Switch]

Answer (score 4):

Was having [Virtual Switch Not Found] error - turned out I needed to add my user id to the HyperV Administrators group using Edit Local users and Groups snap-in. Logged out and after logging back in and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Launching the windows command prompt in administrator mode will solve the problem

launch your cmd in administrator mode
and issue the command

```
minishift config set hyperv-virtual-switch "External VM Switch"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this Issue Resolved.?
Have you tried using virtualbox rather than default hyperv.
Also Set environment Variable as below

Set MINISHIFT_HYPERV_VIRTUAL_SWITCH ="External VM Switch"

Answer (score 0):

try this command `minishift config set hyperv-virtual-switch "External VM Switch`, Ensure that you are running power-shell with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

As you are installing on virtualbox, the command should be

```
minishift.exe start --vm-driver virtualbox
```